# What's wrong with my modular arithmetic?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$$x \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$$

Hence we know that $2x \equiv 6 \pmod{4}$. This implies that $2x \equiv 4l + 6$ for some $l$. Hence we can reduce that to $x = 2l + 3$ or $x \equiv 3 \pmod{2}$ Which doesn't make sense. Where's my mistake?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't make sense? If $x \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, then of course $x \equiv 3 \pmod{2}$ too.

Comment: @DanielFischer I figured it didn't make any sense because the modulus is now completely different. Is everytihng ok then..?

Comment: Yes, so far everything is okay. But be aware that you can't get back to $x \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ from $x \equiv 3 \pmod{2}$. The latter also holds if $x \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$.

Comment: $4\mid X\,\Rightarrow\, 4\mid 2X\,\Rightarrow\, 2\mid X$ is correct, but the converse is not true since - while the second arrow reverses, the first does not, e.g. $\,4\mid 2(2)\,$ but $\,4\nmid 2.\,$ Generally scaling by $a$ is an invertible operation $\iff a\,$ is coprime to the modulus (here $2$ is *not* coprime to $4)\ \ $

Comment: you can't multiply $ x \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ by $ 2$ as $ \text{gcd}(2,4)\ne 1$

Comment: @Manjoy Not true. What's true is that it yields a correct congruence but not necessarily an *equivalent* congruence - see my prior comment.

Comment: @Gone $ 3\cdot 2\equiv 3\cdot 4 \pmod6$ does not necessarily imply  $ 2\equiv 4\pmod 6$

Comment: @ManjoyDas Please read more carefully what I wrote.

Comment: @Goldname When in doubts, write ou the congruence definition. You have shown that if $x \equiv 3 \pmod {4}$, then $x \equiv 3 \pmod {2}$. So using divisions, this is if $4 \mid x-3$, then $2 \mid x-3$, which is correct. Maybe this way you can see it better. (or you could use multiples such as $x-3=4n$ versus $x-3=2n$)

Comment: @Gone yes i missed your comment. you are continuously editing your comment. So this happened

Comment: @Manjoy Yes, I expanded my comment to explain why what you wrote "you can't multiply..." is not true (or misleading without elaboration)

Answer (score 1):

If $ ax\equiv ay\; \text{(mod m)}$ and $ gcd(a,m)=1$, then $ x\equiv y\; \text{(mod m)} $.
If $ gcd(a,m)=d$ then $ ax\equiv ay\; \text{(mod m)}\iff  x\equiv y\; (mod\;\dfrac md)$

Answer (score 0):

$6\pmod{2}\equiv 0$ not $3$.

And also $2*x\equiv 4*l\equiv 2*l\equiv 0\pmod{2}$.  So your entire line reads $0\equiv 0\pmod {2}$, which is consistent.

It seems you have some misconception about $6\pmod{2}$ being more like division than modulo arithmetic.

Backing up, and skipping the step where you multiply everything by $2$, $x\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ would also imply $x\equiv 3\equiv 1\pmod{2}$.

*Re: your comment*

> Where did the 6 (mod 2) congruent 0 come from?

$6=2*3$ is divisible by $2$, ergo it is $0\pmod 2$.  That's what the modular equivalence relation says: $a\equiv b$ iff $2|a-b$, and when $b=0$ it's just divisibility.

Comment: Where did the 6 (mod 2) congruent 0 come from?

Answer (score -1):

The following theorem holds:

> Let $m\in \mathbb N \ \backslash \ \{0\}$, for all $a\in \mathbb Z \ \backslash \{0\}$, $b_1,b_2\in \mathbb Z$ we have:
>   $$
> ab_1 \equiv ab_2 \pmod m \Longleftrightarrow b_1\equiv b_2 \pmod{\frac{m}{\text{gcd}(a,m)}}
> $$

So your first operation is legal but is not an equivalence.

In particular, if you multiply both sides of the congruence without multiply the module, then you lose information.

Hence you have:
$$
x\equiv 3 \pmod 4 \Longrightarrow 2x\equiv 6 \pmod 4
$$

But the converse is not true according to the theorem.

Hence, not all $x\equiv 3\pmod 2$ satisfy the first congruence.

To multiply correctly by $2$ we have to write this equivalence (is the theorem in this specific case):

$$
2 x \equiv 2 \cdot 3 \pmod 8 \Longleftrightarrow x\equiv 3 \pmod{\frac{8}{\text{gcd}(2,8)}}
$$

In this way you don't lose infomation and you will not find "strange" things.

Thanks to Sil for the suggestion to point out the problem of my first answer.

Comment: Isn't this statement different from the relation used in wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Properties

Comment: @Goldname You can prove the statement thanks to the relations written in Wikipedia. I Edited the answer in order to be more clear